# Loop through table records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a list of names in it as below

```
+----------+
| CLI_NAME |
+----------+
| A        |
| B        |
| C        |
| D        |
| E        |
+----------+
```

I'd like to loop through this something like

```
for each value in CLI_NAME do
{
   bla bla
}
```

For each value in the table CLI_NAMES, I'd like to loop through and execute the below.

The value selected from the table above needs to go in as a parameter to T_NAME such as T_NAME = "abc" in the query below

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_2(DATE, O_WT)
SELECT 
    F_DATE,
    CASE 
        WHEN
            SUM(
                CASE
                    WHEN
                        F_NAME like 'ty%asd%'
                    THEN
                        F_PKEY
                END
            ) = 1 THEN 1
        WHEN
            SUM(
                CASE
                    WHEN
                        F_NAME like 'ty%asd%'
                    THEN
                        F_PKEY
                END

            ) = 2 THEN 2               
        WHEN
            SUM(
                CASE
                    WHEN
                        F_NAME like 'ty%asd%'
                    THEN
                        F_PKEY
                END
            ) BETWEEN 3 AND 5 THEN  3 
        WHEN
            SUM(
                CASE
                       WHEN
                        F_NAME like 'ty%asd%'
                    THEN
                        F_PKEY
                END

            ) > 5 THEN 5                          
            ELSE 0 
    END AS O_WT
FROM
    TABLE_1 
WHERE 
    F_NAME IN (
        SELECT I_NAME from I_WD WHERE I_I_ID IN (
            SELECT I_MAP_ID FROM T_T_MAP where T_MAP_ID = (
                SELECT T_ID FROM TWD WHERE T_NAME = 'abc'
            )
        )
    ) 
    AND F_DATE between '2015-05-01' and '2015-06-01' 
    AND F_NAME LIKE 'ty%pr%' 
        GROUP BY F_DATE
```

How could I loop through & do this please?

Comment: Why are you summing strings?

Comment: Hello Barmar - Good spot. It should have been F_PKEY. Updated it :-)

Comment: You don't need a loop. Just use an `INNER JOIN` with the table of names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can do what you want using `CROSS JOIN`:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_2(DATE, O_WT)
    SELECT t1.F_DATE,
           (CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN t1.F_NAME like 'ty%asd%' THEN t1.F_PKEY END) = 1 THEN 1
                 WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN t1.F_NAME like 'ty%asd%' THEN t1.F_PKEY END) = 2 THEN 2
                 WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN t1.F_NAME like 'ty%asd%' THEN t1.F_PKEY END) BETWEEN 3 AND 5 THEN 3
                 WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN t1. F_NAME like 'ty%asd%' THEN t1.F_PKEY END) > 5 THEN 5
                 ELSE 0
            END)
        END AS O_WT
    FROM TABLE_1 t1 CROSS JOIN
         CLI_NAMES
    WHERE t1.F_NAME IN (SELECT I_NAME
                        FROM I_WD
                        WHERE I_I_ID IN (SELECT I_MAP_ID
                                         FROM T_T_MAP 
                                         WHERE T_MAP_ID = (SELECT T_ID
                                                           FROM TWD
                                                           WHERE T_NAME = 'abc'
                                                          )
                                        )
                       ) AND
          t1.F_DATE between '2015-05-01' and '2015-06-01' AND
          t1.F_NAME LIKE 'ty%pr%' 
    GROUP BY t1.F_DATE
```

Comment: Hello Gordon - Thank you very much. I'll try this & let you know. In the statement, SUM(CASE WHEN t1.F_NAME like 'ty%asd%' THEN t1.F_PKEY END) , if I'd like to  dd another condition such as SUM(CASE WHEN t1.F_NAME like 'ty%asd%' AND (SUM(F_DURATION)/1000 >2) THEN t1.F_PKEY END) how could I do? By (SUM(F_DURATION)/1000 >2) I mean the actual mathematical a+b type addition, not the count type SUM which I've used to count the number of occurrences. would you be able to help please?

Answer (score 1):

So you want 'abc' in `WHERE T_NAME = 'abc'` replaced with the CLI_NAME?

Does this suffice:

```
select i_map_id from t_t_map where t_map_id in 
(
  select t_id from twd where t_name in (select cli_name from cli_names)
)
```

instead of

```
select i_map_id from t_t_map where t_map_id = 
(
  select t_id from twd where t_name = 'abc'
)
```

It would not quite be the same as a loop. E.g. if 'A' and 'B' lead to the same t_ids, then you'd get the inserts just once instead of twice.

Comment: Hello Thorsten - Thank you heaps. I'll try this out & let you know.

Comment: I see you've accepted Gordon's answer. Okay then I misunderstood your request. You do know that Gordon's query just runs the same inserts for the number of entries in CLI_NAMES, completely oblivious to the names stored in that table, yes?

Comment: Hello Thorsten - I've wanted both of these queries. They have helped me in different places. Thank you heaps.